# Java JFrame clear just an added GLabel

Tags: java, jframe

I'm very new in Java so excuse me if my question seems to be too stupid.

I have an text menu defined into JFrame -> Container -> GCanvas with GLabels like that:

1. Exit
2. Power of number:
3. n Factorial:

I can choose an option number like that:

```
    public int bagaOcifra(){
    IODialog consola = new IODialog();
    int aleg = consola.readInt("Choose a menu option: (0 - exit):");
    return aleg;
}
```

After I choose, let's suppose option 1, I add a new GLabel "result" with result's string and the menu became:

1. Exit
2. Power of number: **The result is: 8**
3. n Factorial:

So, when I'm "come back" and I choose again option 1 I want to remove just the Glabel "reusult" added there: canvas.add(result, 250, 100);.

```
do { 
    int ceAmAles = bagaOcifra();
    switch (ceAmAles) {

    case 0:
    System.exit(0);

    case 1:
    double rezCalculPutere = alegere1.CalculPutere();
    GLabel result= new GLabel("The result is: " + rezCalculPutere);
    canvas.add(result, 250, 100);
    break;

case 2:
        ...

    case 3:
            ...
        }
} while (true);
    }
```

Can I do that, or I must re-add all Canvas objects ?

I mention that:

```
  do { 
    int ceAmAles = bagaOcifra();
    switch (ceAmAles) {

    case 0:
    System.exit(0);

    case 1:
    canvas.remove(result); // <b> it's not working </b>
    double rezCalculPutere = alegere1.CalculPutere();
    GLabel result= new GLabel("The result is: " + rezCalculPutere);
    canvas.add(result, 250, 100);
    break;

case 2:
        ...

    case 3:
            ...
        }
} while (true);
    }
```

I even try to construct an empty GLabel and add over my "result" GLabel but no luck.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is a problem here. I write 0.Exit, 1.Power of number and when I post it it become 1.Exit, 2.Power of number ?!?! Can someone correct that ? Thanks. Leo

Comment: SOLVED :)) construct GLabel outside od loop and call with results.setLabel("The result is:" + rezCalculPutere);. Thank you. Leo